# How to specify operations in a Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm about to get used to [Pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) so I first have to learn/understand them. I'm trying to copy the procedure from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/automate-machine-learning-workflows-pipelines-python-scikit-learn/) but I'm not able to apply it to my case.

There, they write:

```
# create feature union
features = []
features.append(('pca', PCA(n_components=3)))
features.append(('select_best', SelectKBest(k=6)))
feature_union = FeatureUnion(features)
# create pipeline
estimators = []
estimators.append(('feature_union', feature_union))
estimators.append(('logistic', LogisticRegression()))
model = Pipeline(estimators)
# evaluate pipeline
seed = 7
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold)
```

In my case I would like to do the following:

```
estimators = []
estimators.append('standardize', StandardScaler().fit_transform())
prepare_data = Pipeline(estimators)
```

But when using `fit_transform()` I get the error `fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'`. But how can I use this function of `StandardScaler()` inside a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call fit_transform to the Pipeline itself.

```
X = ...
estimators = []
estimators.append('standardize', StandardScaler())
prepare_data = Pipeline(estimators)
X_scaled = prepare_data.fit_transform(X)
```